# invoking client script from server - SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR in my mvc4 web application.
I have a class inheriting from HUB

```
[HubName("Chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub ,IDisconnect  
{
      private void CallMessage(string message)
      {
               Clients.MessagesRecieved(message);
      }
      ....
```

In my client js file I wrote 
$(function () {
    globalChatHub = $.connection.chat;

```
$.extend(globalChatHub, { MessagesRecieved: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
});
```

the question is ,
Is it possible to invoke the client side script "MessagesRecieved function" from a code in my HomeController.cs

let's say somthing like that :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // this is a test
        ChatHub  h = new ChatHub();
        h.CallMessage("hellow");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,
You can call it the same way you call client code:

```
//Define the client method:
globalChatHub.hello = function {alert('hello');}
```

in the server code just write:

```
ChatHub  h = new ChatHub();
        h.Client.hello();
```

the name of the method is case sensitive.

more info in this link [SignalR quick start](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a the `Hub` context for your `ChatHub` with this code:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
```

Then you can call any method you would like on your `ChatHub` or you can call client methods directly. E.g.:

```
context.Clients.All.MessagesRecieved("test");
```

Give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: You really are lifesaver man! Thanks a lot, exactly just what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

In mvc controller, I use following code to call methods in hub

```
DefaultHubManager hd = new DefaultHubManager(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);
var hub = hd.ResolveHub("ChatHub") as ChatHub;
hub.Echo(HttpContext.Session.SessionID, "Hello Echo");
```

In the hub implementation, I prefer to keep the implementation to call clients in Hub to make the code cohesive.

```
public void Echo(string sessionId, dynamic data)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    context.Clients.All.ClientSideMethod(..)
}
```